# Why did I get a wrong result from code like `instance.method`?

Tags: python, class, methods

It is a basic question.
I have written the following code:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self,x=0,y=0):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
    def __str__(self):
        return '({0} , {1})'.format(self.x,self.y)
    def reflect_x(self):
        return Point(self.x,-self.y)
    
p1=Point(3,4)
p2=p1.reflect_x

print(str(p1),str(p2))
print(type(p1),type(p2))
```

Here type of `p1` and type of `p2` are different. I just want `p2` as a point which is the reflected point of `p1` from x-axis. How can I do it?

Comment: Please wrap your code in a codeblock.

Comment: Please don't just describe the results, show them. In this case, your error was so obvious that Celada found it in under a minute, but usually that isn't true just from glancing at the code. That's why seeing the results (`p2` being a "bound method" instead of an "instance") is useful to people trying to diagnose your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I just want p2 as a point which is the reflected point of p1 from x-axis. How can I do it?

Well, then you should call the method `reflect_x` on `p1` and store the result in `p2`, like this:

```
p2 = p1.reflect_x()
```

In your sample code, you did something different:

```
p2 = p1.reflect_x
```

which means you want `p2` to contain `p1`'s `reflect_x` method.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was really stuck in it! Now I have got  the solution.

Answer (score 4):

FYI:

If you want to access `reflect_x` as a member instead of as a method. add `@property` decorator to `reflex_x` method.

like:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self,x=0,y=0):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y

    def __str__(self):
        return '({0} , {1})'.format(self.x,self.y)

    @property
    def reflect_x(self):
        return Point(self.x,-self.y)
```

Answer (score 2):

In python, every name is reference, every thing is object, even it is function or method.
You just use the name `p1.reflect_x`, this is just a reference of an instancemethod object, which is bound to instance `p1`. So when you use `p2 = p1.reflect_x`, you just assign a reference to `p2`, and never call the method yet.

According to this, the statement `return Point(self.x, -self.y)` never run in fact. If you want to run it just call the method with this: `p2 = p1.reflect_x()`.